# How to handle event delegation with priorities?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have this look-a-like code in my app :

```js
let item;

$('.parent').on('click', function () {
  item = $(this).attr('item') || 0; 
});

$('.parent').on('click', '.children', this, function () {
  doSomething();
});
```

```html
<div class="parent" item="50">
  <div class="children">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent" item="51">
  <div class="children">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent" item="52">
  <div class="children">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a parent element with several children in it. Clicking anywhere on the parent element will give me an `item` information, so I will be able to load functions according to this `item` variable on click on children.

My problem is : I have to delegate the onClick event on children to parent element otherwise the events will trigger in this order :

1. Click on any child
2. Click on parent, which is too late because I need `item` variable first

I have a functionality that replaces the parent element if activated, since it was dynamically inserted into the DOM, I have to delegate the onClick event as well, like this :

```js
$('.grandParent').on('click', '.parent', function () {
  item = $(this).attr('item') || 0;
});
```

Now my problem is that the events are triggering in the wrong order again :

1. Click on any child
2. Click on parent

How can I manage to set click event on parent as top priority?

**Edit :**

I will be more specific. I have a messages list on my page, each `.message` element contains the message content but also some functionnalities like edit, delete, set as favorite, like, etc.

Like this :

```html
<div class="message" data-item="1">
  <a class="edit">E</a>
  <a class="delete">X</a>
  <a class="favorite">Fav</a>
  <a class="like">Like</a>
  <div class="content">
    Hello world !
  </div>
</div>
<div class="message" data-item="2">
  <a class="edit">E</a>
  <a class="delete">X</a>
  <a class="favorite">Fav</a>
  <a class="like">Like</a>
  <div class="content">
    Hello world !
  </div>
</div>
```

Each one of those functionnalities will trigger different functions when clicked : edit(), delete(), like(), etc.

All of them will make AJAX requests which will then send the `item` variable to my server in order to know what item has to be impacted by this click.

To avoid repetition in my events handlers, I am trying to get the `data-item` attribute's value with one event bound to click on `.message` element, relying on the bubbling of children elements.

Comment: have a look at `e.stopPropagation()` for the child -https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ and just set the item in the child click too. Although do you even need the parent click?

Comment: No, don't use `Event.stopPropagation()` unless you really, really know what you're doing. Events should (ideally) always propagate.

Comment: And stop using invalid HTML5 attributes. Use `data-item` instead.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, using e.stopPropagation() will prevent my parent event to trigger when I click on any child element, which is not what I want since I need the item variable to be set when I click on any child element

Comment: So why not just set it when you click on the child element instead of binding it to the parent click? You aren't explaining why it needs to be bound to the parent click event

Comment: Because I have 10 children or so in my parent element. Each one of them triggers a different function, so if I'll have to get the item value in every event handler, which makes a lot of repetitions

Comment: @Snyte I think you overcomplicated this task... can you post a bigger picture of what you're building? (code-wise) I still really don't know any more what functions are you talking about - and the click mess you're having... Please [edit] to expand.

Comment: Better than hacking up your code to make only one call - and then how will you know to call the parent click if you only want to do it once but click on several children?  Whether you put that code in the parent or the child click makes no difference, it still gets called the same number of times

Comment: I have a list of messages on my page -> each message element contains the text content but also the possibility to edit, delete, like it, and so on.-> I need to know what message is currently being clicked on and stock it in my `item` variable so I can send it to my AJAX requests when I want to pop the edit form, for example, or which message I want to delete...

Comment: I have edited my post in order to make my request clearer

Comment: Yeah I would always go to the parent in each click event rather than relying on a global - what if a user clicked a load of things really quickly before the ajax had time to fire - your global may not be the value you want and the wrong thing may get deleted

Comment: Well I could block this event while ajax requests are being called, but it's true it would probably mess my item variable, I was just trying to avoid writing the same line over and over in my events handlers, but I guess this is not the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `item` where you actually want it and get rid of the handler on `parent`:

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.children', function () {
  item = $(this).closest('.parent').attr('item');
  doSomething();
});
```

EDIT:

Then get the item when you click on the grandparent:

```
$('.grandParent').on('click', '.children', function () {
  item = $(this).closest('.parent').attr('item');
});
```

EDIT #2:

Based on the OPs updated requirements, do it like this:

```
<div class="message" data-item="1">
  <a class="action edit" data-type="edit">E</a>
  <a class="action delete" data-type="delete">X</a>
  <a class="action favorite" data-type="favorite">Fav</a>
  <a class="like">Like</a>
  <div class="content">
    Hello world !
  </div>
</div>
<div class="message" data-item="2">
  <a class="action edit" data-type="edit">E</a>
  <a class="action delete" data-type="delete">X</a>
  <a class="action favorite" data-type="favorite">Fav</a>
  <a class="like">Like</a>
  <div class="content">
    Hello world !
  </div>
</div>

$(document).on('click','.message .action',function(e) {
   const item = $(this).closest('message').attr('item');
   switch($(this).data('type')) {
     case 'edit': doEdit(item); break;
     case 'delete': doDelete(item); break;
     case 'favorite': doFavorite(item); break;
   }
});
```

See, one event handler?

It's a very common pattern to do what you're doing. In the absence of a more robust framework (e.g. React), then using plain jQuery this is how it should be done.

Comment: I have like 10 events linked to my children elements, and there will probably be more in the future. So, the point of having only one event that fetches the item value is to avoid repetitions like this...

Comment: @Snyte - see my edit. The point is, you shouldn't be using "multiple" event handlers at all - you only need one, get the `item` in that event handler

Comment: Since when `item` become a valid HTML5 attribute?

Comment: the option you have is best because it doesnt potentially create global variables...doSomething could potentially be passed the item

Comment: @Snyte - see my updated answer based on your updated post. You still only need one handler. I used to write code like this all the time back in the day, your pattern is very common.